# unable to login again after screen lock- also gnome hangs if able to login

Tags: 18.10

I'm unable to log in again after the screen gets locked. I've to press `ctrl + alt + F4` to login and then finally the login screen appears. though after logging in for 10 mins. gnome starts behaving weirdly (nothing opens like gnome-terminal, etc it happens when I press the show  applications button) and requires a system restart to get things working,

How do I rollback this update? I ready to trade my `not working fingerprint scanner` with system stablity